# Selenium 4 + webdriver_manager: executable_path is deprecated. How to use for Firefox?

Tags: selenium, firefox, automation, webdriver-manager

I'm moving my test project from Selenium 3 to Selenium 4 and I'm getting warnings about "executable_path" deprecation. I couldn't find the proper way to use webdriver_manager for Firefox with Selenium 4 so I'm still using the "executable_path".
They also haven't updated their doc here: https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
```

Does anyone have the solution for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I fixed the issue thanks to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VMzmVFA-Gps

The correct usage should be:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

@staticmethod
def get_local_firefox_driver(options):
    service = Service(GeckoDriverManager().install())
    driver = Firefox(
        service=service,
        options=options,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Firefox(GeckoDriverManager().install())
```

Comment: you did literally the same as in my question)

Comment: My question is about how to use webdriver manager with Firefox WITHOUT using deprecated things like executable_path

Comment: Corrected my mistake - that is not what I meant, please see above

Comment: nope, this won't work as the first argument for WebDriver object is "firefox_profile". The issue is that the "executable_path" is deprecated in Selenium 4 but there's no info about how to use the webdriver manager with it right now. Passing the "executable_path" still works but I'd like to get rid of warnings like this:
DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object